How to fix missing GoRouter.routeInformationProvider in Flutter?
I'm currently working through the Flutter 'Boring to Beautiful' codelab and encountered an error while trying to run the project from the boring_to_beautiful/step01 package in Chrome. The specific issue seems related to the GoRouter.routeInformationProvider, which may not have been correctly initialized or passed to the router constructor. Below is the error message I received:
Error: Did you forget to pass in GoRouter.routeInformationProvider to the router constructor?
I obtained this error directly from my browser console. Here is a link to the codelab for reference: Flutter Boring to Beautiful Codelab.
What I have tried:

I have double-checked the code to ensure that GoRouter.routeInformationProvider is initialized and passed correctly, but the error persists.
I searched for similar issues but couldn't find specific solutions related to my case.

Question:
What steps should I take to correctly set up GoRouter.routeInformationProvider in the Flutter project to resolve this error?
